# libvlc get media type (audio or video)

Tags: c, linux, gtk, libvlc

embedding vlc in a gui I want to adapt the gui, whether video or audio file is opened. There is a struct storing the information, but no function to access, I think. So is there a function like libvlc_media_get_type() that returns, an indicator for audio or video?

Answer (score 0):

Call [`libvlc_media_tracks_get`](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media.html#ga33f5fef54e3750ab55744007e0e80f02) to get ahold of the media track information.

From there you can check the [`libvlc_track_type_t`](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media.html#ga129b51e2123512ef5c89e935804d94e4) of each tracks.